# Modelica Programming: fixed constraint in 'for loop' -- for Multistage Constant Current Battery Charging

Tags: for-loop, constraints, modelica

I want to perform Multistage Constant Current Battery Charging in Modelica.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
model BatteryCharge
constant Real Voltage0 = 3;
parameter Real Current_vec[5] = {0.01,0.005,0.004,0.003,0.002};
Real Voltage;
Real Current;
// Integer k;
// algorithm
// k := 1;
// Current := Current_vec[k];
// Voltage := Voltage0 + Current * time;
// 
// if Voltage > 4 then
//    k := k+1;
// end if;

algorithm
for k in 1:5 loop
Current := Current_vec[k];
Voltage := Voltage0 + Current * time;

if Voltage > 4 then
   break;
end if;

end for;

end BatteryCharge
```

I do really need help.

Pls do not ask me to do this in matlab since this is only one simple case of a part of my programming code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing units of current, voltage and time.  So, it is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.
However, if you are trying to just generate voltage as a function of time, you could just use a Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable to give you voltage.